# Display all respective rows from a particular date

Tags: php, mysqli

Can you all please do me a favor ? I am stuck at one place. I want to display all records from a particular date in loop.

for eg. I have 8 records of 29 march, then I want to display header of 29 march and show all the records of 29 march via loop inside a div.

I have 12 records of 29 march and 10 records of 27 march. So far I have been successful in showing 27 march and 29 march dates from a loop via GROUP BY clause but all the records are not showing inside a particular date

Instead of showing all 12 records of 29 march, I am getting only 1 row for each date. I am attaching screenshots and codes for better understanding. What I am getting is below:

[image]

As you can see above, I am getting only 1 row for each date instead of all rows related to that date

What I want is below: [image]

Not good editing haha...But I hope it gives you all clear idea as what I want to accomplish. All rows of 29 march via loop and all rows of 27 march via loop. I have attached codes...Please see what can be done

Code (PHP & MYSQLI)

```
<?php

    $Prepare_Dealers_Purchases_Query = "SELECT * FROM `purchases` WHERE `DealerEmailAddress` = '$ShowDealerEmailAddress' GROUP BY `PurchaseDate` ORDER BY `InvoiceID` DESC";

    $Fire_Dealers_Purchases_Query = mysqli_query($CreateConnection, $Prepare_Dealers_Purchases_Query);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($Fire_Dealers_Purchases_Query) == 0) {
        echo "<div id='userFeedbackPanel' style='margin:15% auto;padding:10px;'><table id='feedbackDataStyling' cellspacing='5' cellpadding='5'><tr><td>You have not purchased any product yet</td></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr><td><a onClick=\"$.fn.openProductSelectionBox();\" class=\"StartShoppingButton\"><i class=\"fa fa-shopping-cart fa-lg\"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Start Shopping</a></td></tr></table></div>";
    } else {
        while($Show_Purchases = mysqli_fetch_array($Fire_Dealers_Purchases_Query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

            if($Show_Purchases['SelectedProduct'] == "Regular Colours") {
                $Shade_Colour = $Show_Purchases['SelectedShade'];
                $Purchase_Date = $Show_Purchases['PurchaseDate'];

                $Prepare_Dealers_Purchases_As_Per_Date_Query = "SELECT * FROM `purchases` WHERE `DealerEmailAddress` = '$ShowDealerEmailAddress' AND `PurchaseDate` = '$Purchase_Date' ORDER BY `InvoiceID` DESC";

                $Fire_Dealers_Purchases_As_Per_Date_Query = mysqli_query($CreateConnection, $Prepare_Dealers_Purchases_As_Per_Date_Query);

                echo "<div align='left'>".$Show_Purchases['PurchaseDate']."</div><br>";
                while($Show_Purchases_As_Per_Date = mysqli_fetch_array($Fire_Dealers_Purchases_As_Per_Date_Query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                    echo "<div id='userFeedbackPanel'><table id='feedbackDataStyling' cellspacing='5' cellpadding='5'><tr><td style='background:$Shade_Colour;border-radius:5px;width:54px;height:64px;'></td><td>You purchased ".$Show_Purchases_As_Per_Date['SelectedQuantity']." boxes of ".$Show_Purchases_As_Per_Date['SelectedProduct']." worth <i class='fa fa-inr'></i> ".$Show_Purchases_As_Per_Date['FinalAmount']." by using ".$Show_Purchases_As_Per_Date['PaymentMethod']." of ".$Show_Purchases_As_Per_Date['BankName']." at ".$Show_Purchases_As_Per_Date['PurchaseTime']." on ".$Show_Purchases_As_Per_Date['PurchaseDate']."</td></tr></table></div><br>";
                    }
                } else {
                    $Product_Image = $Show_Purchases['SelectedProductImage'];

                    echo "<div align='left'>".$Show_Purchases['PurchaseDate']."</div><br><div id='userFeedbackPanel'><table id='feedbackDataStyling' cellspacing='5' cellpadding='5'><tr><td><img src='$Product_Image' width='54' height='64'></td><td>You purchased ".$Show_Purchases['SelectedQuantity']." boxes of ".$Show_Purchases['SelectedProduct']." worth <i class='fa fa-inr'></i> ".$Show_Purchases['FinalAmount']." by using ".$Show_Purchases['PaymentMethod']." of ".$Show_Purchases['BankName']." at ".$Show_Purchases['PurchaseTime']." on ".$Show_Purchases['PurchaseDate']."</td></tr></table></div><br>";

            }
        }
    }
?>
```

I am using 2 while loops. 1 loop for getting all dates and other loop for getting rows of that particular date. Please show me where I am making mistake. Thank you all...

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're going there:

```
else {
    $Product_Image = $Show_Purchases['SelectedProductImage'];

    echo "<div align='left'>".$Show_Purchases['PurchaseDate']."</div><br><div id='userFeedbackPanel'><table id='feedbackDataStyling' cellspacing='5' cellpadding='5'><tr><td><img src='$Product_Image' width='54' height='64'></td><td>You purchased ".$Show_Purchases['SelectedQuantity']." boxes of ".$Show_Purchases['SelectedProduct']." worth <i class='fa fa-inr'></i> ".$Show_Purchases['FinalAmount']." by using ".$Show_Purchases['PaymentMethod']." of ".$Show_Purchases['BankName']." at ".$Show_Purchases['PurchaseTime']." on ".$Show_Purchases['PurchaseDate']."</td></tr></table></div><br>";
}
```

There is no while loop here, so only one line is displayed. Add the same while loop as you did in the if statement and it should be fine :)